# How to add the path for publickey.xml file to the InputStream in android? Where to put the file publickey.xml?

Tags: android, xml, rsa, inputstream, public-key-encryption

//how to place the path for publickeyfile.xml here?

```
InputStream in =
```

//the objectipnutstream that gets the inputstream

```
  ObjectInputStream oin =
new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
  try {
BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);

  } catch (Exception e) {
throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
  } finally {
oin.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a res>raw folder in the project
2. put the publickeyfile.xml file in the new folder
3. "Inputstream is = myResources.openRawResource(R.raw.publickeyfile)"

...it should work